# Is attention mechanism really attention or just looking back at memory again?

Tags: deep-learning, attention-model

When reading attention mechanism, I am confusing about the term attention. Is it the same with our attention nature as described in it usual definition?

Comment: https://github.com/neqkir/attention-mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attention, as introduced in [Attention Is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762), IMHO, is quite similar to what our brains use as the attention mechanism.

We have something named LGN in our brains responsible for filtering out unnecessary information for the task at hand. For instance, if I start looking for my keys, my brain is going to pay less attention to objects with a color other than silver or gold (hopefully). Now, I'm not aware of the higher level attention mechanisms of the human brain. However, the one thing that's clear is that information is passing through each layer before the attention and represented in the form of neural activities.

When you feed your artificial model representation of the world's current state, information is going to be represented as tensors and, similarly, attention allows you to see what you need to see to make the best decision (similar to finding keys).

Comment: Attention as used in NMT has nothing to do with how "sensory attention" works in the brain. At best, it could be framed as a "response selection" mechanism. The former is a form of exogenous attention (though it could be endogenous too) and the latter is purely endogenous -- feedback from a higher level associative memory network guides the selection of the next response (choice of word in this case). So, calling it attention was a bad choice. There's 100 years of cognitive/neuro science/psychology research on attention.

Answer (score 2):

For example in machine translation task, intuitively that’s equivalent outputting a translated word, and then going back through all of your internal memory of the text in order to decide which word to produce next. That seems like a waste, and not at all what humans are doing. In fact, it’s more akin to memory access, not attention, which in my opinion is somewhat of a misnomer (more on that below). Still, that hasn’t stopped attention mechanisms from becoming quite popular and performing well on many tasks.